# Times New Roman with LaTeX (mathptmx)

Tags: fonts, math-operators

Is it possible to change the look of `\infty` when using `mathptmx`? It looks horribly small compared to the other characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following defines a `\Infty` from `mathpazo`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Symbols}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}% Palatino
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Infty}{\mathord}{Symbols}{"31}
\begin{document}

\Huge$\infty$ $\Infty$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with Times (New) Roman fonts, you could look into using either the `mtpro2` package (the "lite" subset of this package is free of charge) or the `newtxmath` package. Both packages will give you lots of symbols, in addition to the infinity symbol, that look a lot better than what's provided by the `mathptmx` package.

First, just for reference, the look of the infinity symbol generated by the `mathptmx` package as well as the MWE's source code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}\Huge
$\infty$
\end{document}
```

Replacing `\usepackage{mathptmx}` with `\usepackage{mtpro2}`, one gets:

[image]

Finally, using `\usepackage{newtxmath}` instead, one gets:

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed! I posted this a long while ago and nowadays I would always recommend using mtpro2 instead of mathptmx

Comment: Of course, mtpro2 is commercial; so you won't want to use it for everything, unless you aren't so extravagant as to want italic bolded text; or you are willing to pay.

Comment: @CodeLurker - I took care to write in the first paragraph of my answer that the "lite" subset of the full `mtpro2` package is available free of charge. The lite subset is all that's needed to generate the infinity symbol shown above.